# How to create a Nunit.xml test runner like we have with Testng.xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nunit

TestNG.xml file is a configuration file that helps in organizing our tests. It allows us to create and handle multiple test classes, define test suites and tests.

It makes it easier by controlling the execution of tests by putting all the test cases together and run it under one XML file. Or if I want to only run one then I can simply do that in the configuration. This also help with integration with Jenkins to pick this file to execute as the Job.

Here are some of benefits that we can achieve with testng

It provides parallel execution of test methods.
It allows the dependency of one test method on another test method.
It helps in prioritizing our test methods.
It allows grouping of test methods into test groups.
It supports the parameterization of test cases using @Parameters annotation.
It helps in Data-driven testing using @DataProvider annotation.
It has different types of assertions that help in validating the expected results with the actual results.
It has different types of HTML reports, Extent reports, etc. for a better and clear understanding of our test summary.
It has listeners who help in creating logs.

I can not find any example of this in Nunit we we have any thing like this?

Example of Testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Practice Suite">
  <test name="Test Basics 1">
      <parameter name="emailid" value="tester456@gmail.com"/>
      <parameter name="password" value="test@123"/>
      <classes>
      <class name="practiceTests.testParameters"/>
      </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test --> 
   
  <test name="Test Basics 2">    
    <parameter name="emailid" value="tester789@gmail.com"/>
    <classes>
       <class name="practiceTests.testOptional"/>
    </classes>
     
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: I think the test cases are classes.  So you can deserialize your xml into classes and then run the test.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit

Comment: Not clear exactly what you are asking for. The title "How to create..." seems to say you want to write a runner like TestNG but using .NET and working like or with NUnit. That's possible, of course, but a big job - as big as writing NUnit or JUnit or TestNG itself.

One thing for sure, NUnit does not currently have a way to restructure tests from the outside as is done in the testng.xml file. The organization is defined, within the test assembly itself. Different frameworks work differently.

Comment: @Charlie do we have anything like Testng.xml in Nunit to control what tests I want to run and which method I want to run.

Comment: Generally, how the execution of tests is controlled is dependent on the runner, not the framework. So you have to tell us the specific runner you are using or want to use. Without that, the answer is basically "It depends."

Comment: when you "specific runner" what do you mean?